# ImageView over ImageView in a GridView

Tags: android, gridview, imageview

i am trying to use an ImageView over an ImageView in a GridView. I already found this quesiton [Android, ImageView over ImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11468146/android-imageview-over-imageview) and it is really familiar with my problem, but i want to use this Layout descripted in the question inside a GridView.

So i created a .xml-file containing the `<GridView></GridView>` (i think this is not really useful to show, so i skip this file) and a .xml-file with the layout i want to use in every cell in the gridview. This is the following file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:id="@+id/rl_act_question_list_alternative" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_question_list_country"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:src="@drawable/germany" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_question_list_solved"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:src="@drawable/icon_question_solved" />
```

As the next step i am creating a subclass of a `BaseAdapter` overriding the method `getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)` with the following code:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if (convertView == null) { 
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(ActivityLevelsAlternative.this).inflate(R.layout.act_question_list_alternative_item, null);
            }

            ImageView mCountry = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_question_list_country);
            ImageView mIconSolved = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_question_list_solved);

            final VOQuestion question = mLevel.getAllQuestions().get(position);
            mCountry.setImageResource(question.getPicture());
            mIconSolved.setImageResource(mPrefManager.isQuestionSolved(question.getId()) ? R.drawable.icon_question_solved : R.drawable.icon_question_unsolved);

            convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityQuestion.class);
                    i.putExtra(ActivityQuestion.QUESTION_ID, question.getId());
                    ActivityLevelsAlternative.this.startActivity(i);
                }
            });

            return convertView;
        }
```

But the the result is not the expected... see: http://q63i.img-up.net/Screenshotc656.png

My question: how can i get the check mark over the country image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change your check mark image like this:

```
<ImageView  
android:id="@+id/iv_question_list_solved"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:layout_alignTop="@id/iv_question_list_country"
android:layout_alignLeft="@id/iv_question_list_country"
android:layout_alignRight="@id/iv_question_list_country"
android:layout_alignBottom="@id/iv_question_list_country"/>
```

Comment: It worked, the check mark is now over the country image. But is there a chance to get the check mark on the right bottom corner and not over the whole image (like in this picture http://i.stack.imgur.com/5cr7i.jpg)?

Comment: You can create another layout which makes the bottom image as the background, and put the check mark image over this layout, then you can drag it to the corner