# Scrollable ImageView with ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-imageview

I have an ImageView i.e. Cover Photo. Another ImageView i.e. profile picture and a textview i.e. name within Coverphoto. There is a listview below this cover photo. I want to make the whole layout scrollable i.e. Cover photo layout should also scroll up with Listview. I've tried  list.addHeaderView but how do merge coverphoto with profile photo and name in list.addheaderview?

Comment: Use your listview inside a nestedscrollview.

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: http://ivankocijan.xyz/android-nestedscrollview/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put all of them (cover-photo, profile-photo, names, etc)  in single layout (e.g. `LinearLayout` | `RelativeLayout`) and then Inflate them and add to your `Listview`.

Your code may be something like this :

```
View profielView = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.view_your_profile, mListView, false);
mListView.addHeaderView(profileView);
```

Your `view_your_profile` is something like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout_profile_header_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <!-- cover photo -->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_profile_cover"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <!-- username  -->
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:text="@string/icon_chevron_left"
                android:textColor="@color/white_transparent_30" />

            <!-- profile photo -->
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"/>

        </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

There is also better way using `RecyclerView` with different view type you can find good tutorial [here](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Heterogenous-Layouts-inside-RecyclerView).

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a RelativeLayout for your cover photo and put the profile picture and textview inside it, in a file named header.xml for example.

You can refer to these questions:

[Android, ImageView over ImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11468146/android-imageview-over-imageview)

[Adding text to ImageView in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404582/adding-text-to-imageview-in-android)

So, after making your header.xml, you can add it to your ListView with your cover photo, profile picture, text, and it will be scrolled as you scroll your list view!